# react testing, userEvent not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have some login code

```
      <Grid className={classes.container} item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <TextField data-testid='employeeId' className={classes.input} value={employeeId} onChange={handleChange} label="Employee id" variant="outlined" />
        {(employeeId && employeeId.length > 0)?
          <Button className={classes.button} disableElevation onClick={onSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary">Login</Button>:
          <Button className={classes.button} disableElevation variant="contained" disabled>
           Login
          </Button>
        }
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

when user enters name, and clicks login, user is navigated to the home page. I wrote tests to check that the login code should not be present after submitting. App behaves as expected but tests to check whether login page has stopped displaying fail.

```
  render(<App/>);
  userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId('employeeId'), 'aryan');
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/login/i));
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/home screen/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByTestId('employeeId')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-glitter-wjpye?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I can't see the test from your question in the codesanbox.

Comment: It's in App.test.tsx file.

Comment: I'm just seeing errors in the console.

Comment: i can see only one warning and I found the solution. I was material-ui TextBox and that provides a wrapper over input. Should not test using test-id.

Comment: Cool, was about to suggest that alright. You should try and find elements like a user would so getByRole is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

When checking if an element is not present, you have to use `queryBy` instead. `queryBy` can handle null cases, whereas `getBy` cannot (by design). So this should do it:

`expect(screen.queryByTestId('employeeId')).not.toBeInTheDocument();`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. I was using material-ui TextBox for input and putting a test-id on the TextBox. It won't work because TextBox is just a wrapper and it should be something like

```
userEvent.type(screen.getByRole('textbox'), 'aryan');
```

Now tests are running fine.